# Como acessar um seletor dentro de outro em jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Estou tentando acessar as div's da classe '.contentParagraph' especifico de cada uma das div's '.content', para que os eventos de uma div não interfira no evento da outra, segue o código:

http://jsfiddle.net/turiba/tpz1gka3/

Se voces observarem, o paragrafo na primeira div '.content' aparece mesmo que eu passe o mouse emcima das outras div's,  como faço para que isso não aconteça?

Qualquer outra observação em meu código será bem-vinda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duas coisas:

Primeiro, colocar o código do jQuery no bloco de Javascript do JSFiddle é crime. Se você olhar o canto esquerdo superior do Fiddle, tem uma opção lá para incluir jQuery automaticamente ;)

Segundo: você pode buscar elementos que são descendentes de outro elemento. Uma vez que você declarou o evento para todos os elementos da classe `content`:

```
$('.content').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this).animate({
       width: '+=750px',
       opacity: '+=0.65'
   });

   $('.contentParagraph').fadeTo('fast',1);
});
```

Você pode substituir a instrução na última linha por:

```
$(this).find('.contentParagraph').fadeTo('fast',1);
```

O método [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) encontra os descendentes do elemento no qual é chamado, que atendam a condição de pesquisa que você passar. Mas isso não é eficiente. Você vai fazer uma busca toda vez que disparar o evento. No seu caso são poucos elementos e pode até ser rápido, mas se algum dia seu HTML inchar, isso pode prejudicar a performance.

Consigo pensar em algumas alternativas, que você pode experimentar:

Criar um dicionário de ids dos elementos das classes `content` para os elementos da classe `contentParagraph`. Algo como:

```
var contentDictionary: {
    content1: $("#paragraph1"),
    content2: $("#paragraph2"),
    content3: $("#paragraph3")
    /**etc., etc./
}
```

Daí seu evento ficaria algo como:

```
$('.content').mouseenter(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.animate({
        width: '+=750px',
        opacity: '+=0.65'
    });

   contentDictionary[that.id].fadeTo('fast',1);
});
```

A segunda alternativa é dar uma classe a mais para os `content` dentro do evento `mouseenter`, e tirar essa classe extra no evento `mouseleave`. Daí você aplica uma visibilidade diferente aos `contentParagraph` de acordo com a classe do elemento pai.

E tem uma que requer menos esforço ainda. Faça os `contentParagraph` serem do mesmo tamanho que os `content`. Daí utilize o evento `mouseenter` e `mouseleave` no `contentParagraph`, e não no `content` ;) a partir do `contentParagraph`, você pode obter o `content` exclusivo dele utilizando a função [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) do jQuery. Assim:

```
var content = $(this).parent();
```

Isso é muito mais eficiente do que o `find`. Boa sorte aí!

Comment: opa, valeu, irei tentar todas essas alternativas e vou ver qual que mais se adequa às minhas necessidades.
Agora, eu tenho outro problema o qual gostaria de resolver neste código. Toda vez que passo o mouse na div content ele armazena as chamadas do mouseenter e fica indo e voltando varias vezes, teria alguma maneira de arrumar isso?

Answer (score 3):

Deixo uma nova resposta, já depois de ter uma resposta aceite, pois **isto é possivel só com CSS**. E quanto menos jQuery melhor.

Pode usar transitions no CSS, e acrescentar:

```
transition: width .8s, opacity .5s;  // no .content com transições de 0,8 e 0,5 segundos

opacity: 0;
transition: opacity 1s; // no .contentParagraph com uma transição de 1 segundo
```

E depois acrescentar novo CSS para defenir como se deve comportar o `.content` e o .contentParagraph quando o `.content` tiver um `:hover`

```
/* novo CSS */
 .content:hover {
    width: 900px;
    opacity: 0.65;
}
.content:hover .contentParagraph {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/qh2hk1wm/

Comment: Gostei da dica. Só funciona com navegadores atuais não é?

Comment: @PapaCharlie, atuais e alguns "antigos" também:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: Muito interessante isso, quando consolidado vai ser uma ótima alternativa para dependência de JS para animações.

Comment: +1, especialmente por causa de `"isto é possivel só com CSS. E quanto menos jQuery melhor"`, e acho que a resposta aceita deveria ser esta :)

Comment: Ficou realmente legal, era justamente o que eu queria fazer.
@Renan Irei aceitar a primeira resposta pois foi ela que sanou a dúvida principal.

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um exemplo no [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2z8b3817/) e completei as outras `div`'s com texto para ilustrar.

```
// troque pela linha abaixo
$('.contentParagraph').fadeTo('fast',0)

// Para ele aplicar o efeito no elemento interno 'p'
$(this).children("p").fadeTo('fast',1)
```

---

Você também pode alterar o seguinte.

No script, remover:

```
$('.contentParagraph').hide()
```

No CSS, aplicar estilo:

```
.contentParagraph{display:none}
```